# "Вешать лапшу на уши" — происхождение выражения

Tags: этимология, фразеология

«Вешать лапшу на уши» говорят, когда подразумевают обман, «запудривание» мозгов. Почему «на уши» — это-то понятно. Но почему *именно лапшу*, а не какой-нибудь другой продукт?

Comment: В польском также [есть выражение](https://pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/nawija%C4%87_makaron_na_uszy) "nawijać makaron na uszy" в значении "долго говорить о чем-то, убеждать кого-то интенсивно и красноречиво"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть несколько версий. Во всех версиях лапша как продукт ни при чём. Одни говорят, что это выражение возникло от просторечного глагола 19 века «облапошить» (или «лапшить»), то есть обманывать, красть: *ла пош* по-французски — это карман. Облапошить — очистить карманы или просто обдурить. "Облапошил" созвучно "Он лапшу на уши". А там уже народ сам добавил "вешал".

Но некоторые лингвисты утверждают, что выражение пришло из уголовного жаргона, где значений слова «лапша» много, одно — лоскут ткани (всё, что вытянуто, лапша — провод, блузка, тесто), которым при необходимости можно завязать "развешанные уши"; т.е. кто-то подслушивает, а его вводят в заблуждение, обманывают, чтобы не выдать тайну — "завешивают лапшой", лоскутом, чтоб не всё слышал.
В любом случае, лапша как таковая оказывается совершенно ни при чем.

Answer (score 2):

Я не нашел в интернете указаний на *лингвистов*, возводящих "лапшу на ушах" к облапошить. Хотя переписывается друг у друга, но более напоминает "спинджачную" этимологию.

Мне более по душе уголовное происхождение. Лапша - уголовное дело. Вешать на уши - врать. Лапша на ушах - сфабрикованное дело или что-то подложное, ненастоящее.

Кстати, а что за сложности с самим словом "лапша"? Почему везде "этимология не ясна"? Мне казалось, что тут все вполне прозрачно, родственно "лапа". Смотреть сейчас некогда, может кто объяснит, в чем загвоздка-то?

Comment: >Кстати, а что за сложности с самим словом "лапша"? Почему везде "этимология не ясна"? Мне казалось, что тут все вполне прозрачно, родственно "лапа". 

А как по смыслу *лапша* связана со словом *лапа* ?

Comment: Тесто месят, потом раскатывают - все, пардон, лапами... Не, это так, поверхностно. 
Я потом посмотрю внимательно. Прсто мне странным показалось, что такое "родное" слово по утверждению интренет-источников имеет сомнительную этимологию.

Answer (score 1):

Для меня русский язык - не родной. Я родом из Силезии, пользуюсь польским языком а в быту также его силезским диалектом (тем же т.н. "силезским языком"). И с детства знаю фразу **"nudle wieszać"** (Слово "nudle" - тоже в других регионах Польши не применятеся), которой в литературном польском нет, но она применяется именно в Силезии, - в тех районах Польши, у которых исторических связей с Россией никогда не было.

Это выражение так в буквальном переводе, как и в косвенном смысле означает то же что, "лапшу на уши вешать". Игогда силезец, ничего не говоря, просто пальцем обматываeт невидимой лапшой свое ухо, показывая, что знает как его обманывают.

Употребление этой фразы в силезском диалекте подтверждает также мой папа, который помнит ее с детства (сороковые и пятидесятые годы прошлого века)

Comment: Павел, спасибо, это все очень интересно, но как вы объясняете-то почему такой оборот возник? Был исторический случай, когда кто-то настоящие "нудле" на настоящие уши вешал?

Comment: Объяснения у меня как такого - нет. Просто описал факт того, что в Силезии, это выражение употреблялось эндемично и появилось не позже, чем в послевоенное время.
При этом влияние русского языка на польский наблюдалось в императорской Варшаве, но не в прусской Силезии, которая до 1945 года не только с Россией многого общего не имела.  В отличии от жаргона Варшавы, народная речь силезцев русизмов не знала и не ассимилировала - поэтому предпологаю, что похожее выражение когда-то могло существовать в немецком языке, который повлиял на русскую, - и еще больше на силезскую речь.